# Test statistics for significant change points from First Derivative of GAM smooth?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, generalized-additive-model

I'm using `gratia_0.7.3`

**Edits with changes from Gavin Simpson's comments.**

**Clarification:** I am interested in knowing during which years CPUE changes significantly. I am running these models for 3 species in 3 rivers. I have 3 sets of models the first is changes in angler catch rate, the second is change in fisheries size relative abundance, and the third is changes in age-0 relative abundance. Data here is simulated based on angler catch rate (CPUE) of one species in one river. The second and third set of models use electrofishing survey data.

Based on Comments 1 and 2 I refit models with differing distributions and selected the Tweedie distribution with response `CPUE` in the model formula.

**A few questions** from comments and other posts I've read...

- Assumption: Estimation of the first derivative is unbiased

  - I'm not sure how to check/ensure this?
- To include uncertainty due to smoothing parameter being estimated set `unconditional = TRUE`.

  - Where should I use `unconditional = TRUE` in `predict()`, `derivatives()`, or both?

**First**, I need create `new_data` for the years 2001 to 2021. Below `n = 200` rows are generated using `seq_min_max()` from `gratia` for years 2001 to 2021.

```
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

new_data <- with(sim_dat,
                 tibble( year = seq_min_max( c( min(year):max(year) ), 200) ) )
```

**Second**, I generate a prediction matrix from my current model for `new_dat`.

- I am using `type="link` (as suggested comment 3).
- I'm going to try including `unconditional = TRUE` to include uncertainty due to smooth parameter estimation.

  - **Question:** meant for `predict()`, `derivatives()`, or both?

```
pred_mat <- predict(tw_fit, 
                    newdata = new_data, 
                    type = "link", 
                    se.fit = TRUE,
                    unconditional = TRUE)
```

**Third**, I use `derivatives()` from `gratia` to get the first order derivative with simultaneous ($95\%$) confidence intervals from my `gam()` model fit (`tw_fit`) for the smooth term `s(year)` over the study period (2001 to 2021 in `new_data`).

**Arguments**

> `type = "central"`  type of finite difference used. using central derivative so I am not extrapolating too much beyond the start/end of the time series (as suggested comment 4).

> `n = 200` evaluating the derivative at 200 points suggested in comment 4.

> `eps = 1` to get derivative over an entire year (suggested comment 4)

> `unconditional = TRUE` (**I hope I'm not compounding this by using it in both `pred()` and `derivatives()`?**)

```
fd_tw_fit <- derivatives(tw_fit,
                             term = "s(year)",
                             newdata = new_data,
                             order = 1L,
                             type = "central",
                             n = 200,
                             eps = 1,
                             interval = "simultaneous",
                             n_sim = 10000,
                             unconditional = TRUE)
signifD <- function(x, d, upper, lower, eval = 0) {
  miss <- upper > eval & lower < eval
  incr <- decr <- x
  want <- d > eval
  incr[!want | miss] <- NA
  want <- d < eval
  decr[!want | miss] <- NA
  list(incr = incr, decr = decr)
  }
m2.dsig <- signifD(x = pred_mat$fit, 
               d = fd_tw_fit$derivative,
                   upper = fd_tw_fit$upper, 
               lower = fd_tw_fit$lower,
                   eval = 0)
incr <- which( !(is.na(m2.dsig$incr)) ) %>%
  fd_tw_fit[.,]

decr <- which( !(is.na(m2.dsig$decr)) ) %>%
  fd_tw_fit[.,]
```

**Plotting the derivative and simultaneous confidence intervals.**

```
draw(fd_tw_fit,
     alpha = 0.2) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -45)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2001, 2021, 1),
                     labels = seq(2001, 2021, 1)) +
  labs(title = "Simultaneous CI first derivative tw() GAM") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image: First Derivative Plot]

**Plotting GAM fit on response scale**
Transforming predicted data to the response scale with `exp()` (comment 3).

```
# Calculate upper and lower confidence Intervals
upper_2se <- (pred_mat$fit) + (pred_mat$se.fit*2)  
lwr_2se <- (pred_mat$fit) - (pred_mat$se.fit*2)

# Transform to Response scale
upper_2se <- exp(upper_2se)
lwr_2se <- exp(lwr_2se)
pred_fit <- exp(pred_mat$fit)
new_data %<>% dplyr::mutate(pred = pred_fit,
                        lwr_2se = lwr_2se,
                        upr_2se = upper_2se,
                        change_point = ifelse(new_data$year %in% incr$data,
                                              "incr",
                                              ifelse(new_data$year %in% decr$data,
                                                         "decr",
                                                         "NS") ) %>%
                              factor())
raw_dat <- sim_dat %>%
  select(year,
         CPUE) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(change_point = "NS" %>% factor())
```

**create ggplot** Response scale with Change Points

```
ggplot(data = new_data, aes(x = year, y = pred, color = change_point))+
  geom_path(aes(group = 1),
            size = 1.25) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("NS" = "black",
                                "incr" = "blue",
                                "decr" = "red")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr_2se, ymax = upr_2se),
              colour = "grey",
              alpha = 0.2,
              linetype = "blank") +
  geom_point(data = raw_dat,
             aes(x = year, y = CPUE, color = change_point),
             size = 1.5,
             alpha = 0.2,
             colour = "black")
```

[image: Response scale Change Point Plot]

**New simulated data**

```
sim_dat <- structure(list(year = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021
), eff_hrs = c(232, 90, 696, 702, 192, 423, 280, 117, 120, 54, 
54, 1216, 240, 108, 1120, 437, 527.5, 95, 48, 702, 144, 45, 692, 
54, 466, 612, 48, 152, 810, 48, 5112, 108, 934, 162, 56, 1097, 
48, 64, 720, 405, 846, 2466, 289, 360, 567, 189, 702, 1440, 289, 
90, 928, 243, 1512, 98, 738, 48, 486, 64, 88, 232, 810, 128, 
304, 1216, 64, 136, 648, 99, 555, 1476, 315, 1392, 432, 555, 
1785, 540, 104, 656, 1288, 135, 516.5, 1785, 666, 112, 135, 72, 
378, 232, 144, 180, 50, 45, 126, 162, 112, 56, 1328, 252, 486, 
32, 585, 1008, 1926, 40, 648, 333, 119, 144, 32, 720, 117, 1926, 
648, 40, 559, 400, 352, 288, 1404, 468, 1404, 180, 468, 774, 
162, 162, 99, 216, 288, 936, 1156, 1071, 304, 1116, 1071, 1292, 
288, 324, 256, 992, 1216, 243, 630, 1296, 296, 702, 40, 99, 328, 
1072, 216, 48, 972, 1206, 80, 48, 64, 225, 70, 144, 765, 904, 
38.5, 14, 220, 270, 1098, 756, 756, 200, 680, 595, 266, 333, 
1782, 99, 32, 48, 252, 704, 351, 864, 972, 30, 48, 414, 2000, 
342, 112, 736, 144, 198, 96, 1984, 2232, 653, 570, 48, 342, 117, 
135, 88, 396, 135, 135, 108, 918, 2000, 48, 64, 117, 846, 639, 
234, 936, 144, 72, 468, 333, 72, 54, 459, 828, 684, 56, 752, 
42, 1022, 846, 944, 744, 200, 324, 900, 584, 80, 360, 540, 76.5, 
112, 2432, 99, 20, 288, 320, 408, 1008, 35, 112.5, 306, 792, 
378, 450, 1080, 24, 234, 288, 96, 68, 72, 243, 110, 75, 126, 
176, 49.5, 94, 64, 222, 648, 225, 49.5, 50, 90, 65, 90, 70, 81, 
264, 70, 558, 874, 128, 904, 371, 896, 96, 2340, 943.5, 1008, 
31.5, 32, 52, 504, 216, 28, 52, 32, 40, 560, 136, 180, 240, 720, 
64, 288, 800, 52, 736, 32, 32, 24, 288, 288, 352, 810, 384, 752, 
432, 810, 252, 720, 848, 594, 252, 136, 944, 368, 108, 80, 60, 
768, 405, 352, 1008, 70, 1009, 384, 85, 40, 112, 40, 1120, 72, 
4000, 324, 255, 55, 128, 32, 128, 176, 50, 928, 24, 240, 40, 
64, 128, 28, 184, 248, 32, 592, 20, 72, 800, 98, 48, 1170, 297, 
42, 30, 66, 44, 88, 1080, 96, 112, 336, 736, 192, 624, 369, 1088, 
176, 144, 104, 2196, 432, 128, 144, 585, 120, 216, 45, 2250, 
80, 816, 992, 256, 240, 540, 72, 45, 1170, 208, 200, 101, 224, 
387, 312, 18, 45), num = c(6, 0, 8, 4, 12, 16, 0, 18, 9, 86, 
8, 1, 6, 26, 4, 48, 21, 10, 0, 26, 3, 85, 9, 98, 5, 14, 21, 40, 
1, 15, 7, 53, 32, 8, 35, 20, 9, 36, 66, 39, 10, 37, 14, 14, 4, 
8, 11, 5, 4, 13, 3, 106, 10, 19, 125, 66, 56, 3, 2, 37, 3, 23, 
8, 23, 37, 191, 44, 14, 113, 4, 27, 6, 46, 11, 7, 51, 8, 3, 72, 
21, 11, 54, 24, 24, 47, 58, 3, 20, 5, 5, 23, 14, 2, 1, 2, 5, 
0, 0, 9, 10, 9, 1, 41, 16, 0, 4, 2, 1, 9, 2, 1, 40, 3, 0, 5, 
3, 10, 20, 9, 19, 14, 3, 2, 8, 9, 19, 7, 15, 40, 41, 100, 58, 
19, 42, 12, 71, 85, 14, 29, 2, 33, 34, 75, 72, 21, 59, 2, 17, 
10, 16, 7, 53, 6, 3, 11, 4, 3, 3, 80, 58, 3, 5, 51, 10, 3, 1, 
18, 0, 45, 14, 56, 0, 28, 53, 45, 29, 63, 79, 2, 13, 22, 34, 
9, 54, 122, 41, 105, 105, 0, 14, 8, 35, 38, 77, 89, 37, 202, 
87, 10, 12, 4, 62, 10, 20, 12, 225, 18, 74, 0, 177, 85, 16, 16, 
12, 30, 34, 22, 118, 195, 154, 87, 21, 0, 180, 61, 70, 58, 124, 
76, 58, 21, 123, 19, 85, 60, 67, 72, 175, 17, 13, 48, 5, 9, 20, 
28, 9, 12, 190, 33, 65, 6, 106, 24, 13, 163, 25, 47, 18, 41, 
103, 35, 16, 0, 12, 26, 188, 12, 19, 15, 21, 127, 39, 58, 49, 
73, 183, 181, 208, 110, 131, 8, 10, 28, 60, 4, 20, 16, 63, 2, 
40, 8, 4, 18, 133, 8, 1, 26, 9, 6, 1, 54, 7, 8, 18, 15, 84, 3, 
20, 51, 24, 18, 46, 39, 75, 62, 90, 85, 90, 64, 49, 65, 99, 97, 
81, 65, 31, 91, 6, 34, 44, 75, 34, 10, 20, 27, 15, 15, 26, 25, 
25, 57, 5, 3, 4, 34, 25, 138, 1, 12, 11, 17, 19, 3, 0, 35, 5, 
3, 2, 4, 70, 5, 12, 73, 4, 8, 10, 6, 44, 4, 31, 18, 31, 8, 7, 
27, 9, 20, 24, 77, 64, 1, 18, 29, 74, 27, 4, 53, 60, 40, 37, 
33, 45, 133, 101, 6, 87, 4, 83, 135, 18, 50, 10, 92, 23, 43, 
135, 61, 86, 6, 75, 83, 177, 57, 5), CPUE = c(0.0638297872340425, 
0.0690789473684211, 0.180555555555556, 0.0833333333333333, 0.021505376344086, 
0.0211640211640212, 0.0065359477124183, 0.0305555555555556, 0.0375, 
0.075, 0.00997150997150997, 0.0446428571428571, 0.0493827160493827, 
0.100473933649289, 0.125, 0.0555555555555556, 0.102564102564103, 
0.0229885057471264, 0.0749536178107607, 0.109375, 0.037037037037037, 
0.0718954248366013, 0.09375, 0.0683760683760684, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.175, 0.0592592592592593, 0.0648148148148148, 
0.0276854928017719, 0.0245901639344262, 0.037037037037037, 0.0972222222222222, 
0.0803443328550933, 0.075, 0.0129310344827586, 0.0608108108108108, 
0.0963597430406852, 0.16, 0.0816326530612245, 0.0375, 0.0584795321637427, 
0.0501355013550136, 0.2, 0.0617283950617284, 0.111111111111111, 
0.274509803921569, 0.127941176470588, 0.159090909090909, 0.037037037037037, 
0.0522875816993464, 0.0790598290598291, 0.0582010582010582, 0.1875, 
0.0625, 0.0375, 0.0493827160493827, 0.0596107055961071, 0.0346020761245675, 
0.0474020054694622, 0.14375, 0.1125, 0.0652777777777778, 0.046875, 
0.0862068965517241, 0.018018018018018, 0.0147058823529412, 0.0285714285714286, 
0.0471380471380471, 0.0444444444444444, 0.107142857142857, 0.0384615384615385, 
0.0611111111111111, 0.0990853658536585, 0.062888198757764, 0.0315315315315315, 
0.137212643678161, 0.0925925925925926, 0.111111111111111, 0.0851851851851852, 
0.0318428184281843, 0.0517241379310345, 0.109375, 0.0476190476190476, 
0.162162162162162, 0.111111111111111, 0.0101010101010101, 0.036036036036036, 
0.0285714285714286, 0.0126984126984127, 0.0493827160493827, 0.0166666666666667, 
0.0138888888888889, 0.0756302521008403, 0.0476190476190476, 0.0138888888888889, 
0.0154320987654321, 0.0265625, 0.0238095238095238, 0.00467289719626168, 
0.0488095238095238, 0.0246913580246914, 0.00793650793650794, 
0.03125, 0.0169082125603865, 0.0113636363636364, 0.0123456790123457, 
0.0188253012048193, 0.040983606557377, 0.00555555555555556, 0, 
0.0175438596491228, 0.0125, 0.00467289719626168, 0.0142450142450142, 
0.0111111111111111, 0.0250447227191413, 0.03125, 0.0142045454545455, 
0.0303030303030303, 0.0170940170940171, 0.0432098765432099, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.00641025641025641, 0.025, 0.0135327635327635, 0.0245478036175711, 
0.0672268907563025, 0.030982905982906, 0.0616776315789474, 0.0634920634920635, 
0.0659722222222222, 0.0432098765432099, 0.00657894736842105, 
0.0694444444444444, 0.0416666666666667, 0.0263157894736842, 0.0662931839402428, 
0.0856854838709677, 0.172839506172839, 0.0447530864197531, 0.16015625, 
0.0285467128027682, 0.0896057347670251, 0.0625, 0.00925925925925926, 
0.333333333333333, 0.0444444444444444, 0.0196078431372549, 0.075, 
0.109375, 0.0740740740740741, 0.09375, 0.0833333333333333, 0.00712250712250712, 
0.0299145299145299, 0.101307189542484, 0.0416666666666667, 0.0127659574468085, 
0.0640243902439024, 0.0142450142450142, 0.0689300411522634, 0.138888888888889, 
0.0693069306930693, 0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0977443609022556, 
0.183060109289617, 0, 0.141203703703704, 0.0324074074074074, 
0.1, 0.0535714285714286, 0.0277777777777778, 0.0130813953488372, 
0.0994152046783626, 0.154761904761905, 0.0674603174603175, 0.126436781609195, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0729166666666667, 0.0990338164251208, 0.142663043478261, 
0.090625, 0.111111111111111, 0.0803571428571429, 0.171052631578947, 
0.0484330484330484, 0.139204545454545, 0.0936213991769547, 0.118055555555556, 
0.0416666666666667, 0.101814516129032, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0458937198067633, 
0.0310077519379845, 0.0772569444444444, 0.0727969348659004, 0.0751953125, 
0.133333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 0.0436681222707424, 0.0551301684532925, 
0.0833333333333333, 0.0625, 0.13302034428795, 0.244444444444444, 
0.261363636363636, 0.180555555555556, 0.472222222222222, 0.0681818181818182, 
0.276353276353276, 0.375, 0.28125, 0.316239316239316, 0.115, 
0, 0.0847953216374269, 0.339285714285714, 0.395833333333333, 
0.132716049382716, 0.479166666666667, 0.201058201058201, 0.222222222222222, 
0.2, 0.137096774193548, 0.235042735042735, 0.201388888888889, 
0.211352657004831, 0.388888888888889, 0.35, 0.25, 0.182795698924731, 
0.18018018018018, 0.25, 0.158666666666667, 0.2, 0.245, 0.6, 0.299145299145299, 
0.244444444444444, 0.37037037037037, 0.142857142857143, 0, 0.137345679012346, 
0.119047619047619, 0.277777777777778, 0.221590909090909, 0.424242424242424, 
0.09375, 0.260416666666667, 0.305555555555556, 0.228535353535354, 
0.17989417989418, 0.0990990990990991, 0.2, 0.4, 0.282608695652174, 
0.106666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.144230769230769, 0.242990654205607, 
0.0696022727272727, 0.171717171717172, 0.457516339869281, 0.189964157706093, 
0.311274509803922, 0.129496402877698, 0.253472222222222, 0.177295918367347, 
0.107954545454545, 0.346666666666667, 0.202020202020202, 0.363636363636364, 
0.56, 0.282738095238095, 0.148148148148148, 0.2, 0.270833333333333, 
0.189542483660131, 0.186507936507937, 0.14537037037037, 0.0987654320987654, 
0.101709401709402, 0.0208333333333333, 0.0667726550079491, 0.126984126984127, 
0.204545454545455, 0.0892857142857143, 0.0539083557951483, 0.03125, 
0.0491071428571429, 0.0568376068376068, 0.0961538461538462, 0.346153846153846, 
0.0714285714285714, 0.222222222222222, 0.12037037037037, 0.0515734265734266, 
0.0833333333333333, 0.0833333333333333, 0.114130434782609, 0.125, 
0.0821428571428571, 0.0714285714285714, 0.0944444444444444, 0.375, 
0.103333333333333, 0.134408602150538, 0.125, 0.109375, 0.0833333333333333, 
0.0511363636363636, 0.101190476190476, 0.0524691358024691, 0.134722222222222, 
0.0754716981132075, 0.127604166666667, 0.143097643097643, 0.208333333333333, 
0.11968085106383, 0.257936507936508, 0.1, 0.257936507936508, 
0.122222222222222, 0.12037037037037, 0.190775681341719, 0.119791666666667, 
0.0677083333333333, 0.25, 0.0294117647058824, 0.0880681818181818, 
0.0756578947368421, 0.0572916666666667, 0.227941176470588, 0.126984126984127, 
0.4, 0.06, 0.0679347826086956, 0.0727272727272727, 0.140625, 
0.1, 0.0196078431372549, 0.0797413793103448, 0.0475, 0.0625, 
0.0222222222222222, 0.0617283950617284, 0.058641975308642, 0.223214285714286, 
0.0661764705882353, 0.2, 0.125, 0.0277777777777778, 0.0357142857142857, 
0.032258064516129, 0.0816326530612245, 0.104166666666667, 0.214285714285714, 
0.075, 0.0422297297297297, 0.2421875, 0.166666666666667, 0.1125, 
0.277777777777778, 0.35, 0.0833333333333333, 0.183333333333333, 
0.0134680134680135, 0.0978260869565217, 0.0608888888888889, 0.0925925925925926, 
0.125, 0.241071428571429, 0.0497685185185185, 0.149590163934426, 
0.0902777777777778, 0.0677966101694915, 0.25, 0.178197064989518, 
0.204545454545455, 0.09, 0.339285714285714, 0.015625, 0.0542005420054201, 
0.104166666666667, 0.0303308823529412, 0.00925925925925926, 0.0605646630236794, 
0.110294117647059, 0.0815217391304348, 0.119047619047619, 0.0727040816326531, 
0.165441176470588, 0.0666666666666667, 0.248161764705882, 0.129166666666667, 
0.0769230769230769, 0.17037037037037, 0.174358974358974, 0.306930693069307, 
0.375, 0.271875, 0.0866935483870968, 0.166666666666667, 0.133333333333333, 
0.240384615384615, 0.161835748792271, 0.166666666666667, 0.0786666666666667, 
0.140939597315436, 0.152573529411765, 0.231060606060606, 0.133333333333333
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -414L))
```

Comment: What do you (or your committee) mean by a "test statistic". The derivative itself is a (scaled) difference of means (the respective means being the the two data points over which we computed the derivative. You could use that as the test statistic, and if you want a p-value, you could invert the confidence/simultaneous interval to get one. You could also divide the derivative by it's standard error to get a t-like statistic.

Comment: Or are you interested in the timing of the changepoints? I.e. not the uncertainty in the response or the derivative but the uncertainty in `year` as to when the changes took place? We could do that; its a bit tedious but quite easy once you know how; but no point answering that if it isn't the actual question you/they want an answer to.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thank you for your explanation. I am interested in when the changes take place. I was using gamm() because I had a ARMA() correlation structure in there but wasn't necessary with the data I simulated for the example and left it out to not add more complexity. I'll try your suggestions and post back. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. I'd fit this with the `tw()` family using `gam()` not `gamm()`. You have some 0s, and these aren't allowed in the `Gamma` family so you are adding 1 to your response, but I don't see any reason why you need to use `gamm()` here.
2. Better, assuming you have the `effort`, variable would be to model these as actual **counts** with `poisson()` or `nb()` families and include the effort via an offset term - add `+ offset(log(effort))` to your model formula, where `effort` is the variable that normalises the counts to catch per unit effort. Absent that variable, the `tw()` is the best option.
3. You are computing the confidence interval (`upper_2se` etc) using predictions from the *response* scale and that is incorrect: as your plot shows, the interval contains negative values which just doesn't make sense. instead, use `type = "link"` when predicting, and then form the confidence interval as you do it now, but then backtransform the upper and lower limits and the fitted values to the response scale using the inverse of the link function (in all the cases mentioned — `Gamma`, `tw`, `nb` `poisson` — the link function is `log()`, so you'd want `exp()` for the inverse. That way you'll get a confidence interval that respects the properties of the data.
4. I'd compute the derivative over a much finer grid than you do — you are estimating the derivative over a very small interval around the integer year values.

   This is actually causing you some problems as shown in the last plot; each of the blue spikes should be associated with a red decrease, but because of the crude grid of points you are evaluating the derivative at, you simply aren't seeing the significant decreases. That last red section is also likely spurious.

   If you want an instantaneous measure of the derivative you should do like you do when you plot the smooth and do it for a finer grid, say 100-200 points over the range `min(year)` to `max(year)` with `seq(min(year), max(year), length = 200)` say.

   Or, if you want the derivative over the entire year (?) you would have to increase `eps` to be some much larger value, like `1`, and I would suggest you do a central derivative so you aren't extrapolating too much beyond the start/end of the time series.

Remember these are derivatives on the link (log) scale; they aren't response level changes. Response derivatives is a bit more involved but should be in {gratia} in a few weeks.

I'll try to work up a full example from your data, but I also have some questions which I'll post as comments first. Consider this a WIP.